# Non-US citizen/resident trying to begin trading options and futures

Tags: investing, options, futures, foreign

I'm from Brazil and I already trade shares, options and futures here for ~5 years in the Brazilian stock market. I began trading shares in the US stock market a few months ago using the Passfolio broker, and now I'm trying to trade options and futures but my broker doesn't have options/futures in their platform.

Can I trade options/futures as a non-US resident?